# how to unzip file and save into particaular folder

Tags: node.js, directory

i am trying to unzip a zip file and save into target path

i tried these thing

var zip = new AdmZip(x);

zip.extractAllTo(/*target path*,false);

and then

fs.createReadStream(path/to/arch.zip).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: "targetpath"}));

it is extracting the zip file and save that unzip file into target path.it is fine.

but if i upload the two zip file(it contain same name),it is overwrite that folder.

for example

first if i upload image.zip ,it will be extracted and it will be stored into images(target folder)
       now images folder contain image folder.
again if i upload image.zip,it will be extracted and it will be overwrite image folder

so images folder contain again one image folder.
but if i upload image1.zip file , the images folder contain image and image1 folder.

so how to save even the folder contain the same name.

Comment: You cannot have two different items (directories or files) within the same directory. I.e. you cannot have two different `image` directories inside the `images` directory. (Not in any OS/file system that I know of, anyway)

Comment: store them in separate folders